# Error on clicking 'Screen Options' tab only at Products-related editor screen(s) and for specific user

Tags: javascript, jquery, admin-menu, scripts, screen-options

My client has problems with the `Screen Options` tab and in general with Javascript (or maybe WPBakery) related parts of the Admin screen.

WPBakery-s blue buttons are not displaying to him at all. And it happens only, if he stays on a Product Editor page or on other screen that is Product-related.

---

MY client's screenshot:
[image: WP-Bakery is not loading on my client's computer]

---

My screenshot, at same product
[image: everything loads properly]

For me everything works flawlessly.

We tired the following:

1. with different user (admin)
2. from other browser

DevTools Console gives the following error:

```
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.4.2:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.4.2:2)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3)
    at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3)
    at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:8)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3)
    at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:2)
    at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=hoverIntent,common,hoverintent-js,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,adm&load[chunk_1]=in-comments,suggest,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,word-count,wp-sanitiz&load[chunk_2]=e,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,wp-plupload&ver=5.4.2:11)
(anonymous) @ wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.4.2:2
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3
r.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3
trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3
a.event.trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:8
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3
each @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:2
each @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:2
trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=hoverIntent,common,hoverintent-js,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,adm&load[chunk_1]=in-comments,suggest,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,word-count,wp-sanitiz&load[chunk_2]=e,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,wp-plupload&ver=5.4.2:11
i @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:2
fireWith @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:2
x @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:4
c @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:4
ajax @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:4
l @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=hoverIntent,common,hoverintent-js,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,adm&load[chunk_1]=in-comments,suggest,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,word-count,wp-sanitiz&load[chunk_2]=e,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,wp-plupload&ver=5.4.2:11
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=hoverIntent,common,hoverintent-js,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,adm&load[chunk_1]=in-comments,suggest,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,word-count,wp-sanitiz&load[chunk_2]=e,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,wp-plupload&ver=5.4.2:11
setTimeout (async)
d @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=hoverIntent,common,hoverintent-js,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,adm&load[chunk_1]=in-comments,suggest,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,word-count,wp-sanitiz&load[chunk_2]=e,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,wp-plupload&ver=5.4.2:11
v @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=hoverIntent,common,hoverintent-js,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,adm&load[chunk_1]=in-comments,suggest,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,word-count,wp-sanitiz&load[chunk_2]=e,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,wp-plupload&ver=5.4.2:11
h @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=hoverIntent,common,hoverintent-js,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,adm&load[chunk_1]=in-comments,suggest,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,word-count,wp-sanitiz&load[chunk_2]=e,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,wp-plupload&ver=5.4.2:11
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=hoverIntent,common,hoverintent-js,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,adm&load[chunk_1]=in-comments,suggest,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,word-count,wp-sanitiz&load[chunk_2]=e,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,wp-plupload&ver=5.4.2:11
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3
r.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider&ver=5.4.2:3
```

and i repeat: it's happening only for a specific computer, and seems to be not a user- or browser-level issue. (can it be IP related anyhow?!)

Thank you for any ideas..
Wiktor

Comment: Did you check the network tab to see if all files are loading? If this is ok everywhere else maybe this computer has some security thing that's blocking some js or other files. It's not really a Wordpress problem but I can see the result is that Wordpress is broken, it's more a problem for your client's IT department.

Comment: @mozboz we will check it soon, thank you for the hint!

Comment: @mozboz i'm digging this topic and feel bit overwhelmed at the moment, i'm rather newbie at frontend-debugging especially when i can't easily reproduce the issue on my machine and i got the challenge of tracing the bug in minimized .js, etc. If you can and want, some more elaborate list of tips, directions would be appreciated! Im reading [articles](https://medium.com/@jrullmann/debugging-the-production-web-d36373b9440) about it, nice, but now i can't do enterprise developer approaches, im a single developer in this small-scale project (normal webshop with few hundred products) Cheers! : )

Comment: It's a tricky one. If a website works fine for all of the computers in the world work except one, my approach would be to say that whoever set up that computer is responsible for fixing it, not the people who made the website. Sorry that's not more helpful. You may want to post this in a venue that's more to do with desktop/server support, as it sounds like you need help with diagnosing the OS/network/appliciations of a specific PC, it's not related to Wordpress.

Comment: @mozboz this somewhat makes sense ;). I'm still in that stage that i must identify, whether it's a truly unique case tho. Actually now as i was toggling off/on many options, i happened to fix the problem, when i set the `define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', true );` constant = true..  Which brings us back to question one: why this 'factory default setting' is conflicting with that specific system?.. ;) (as its apparently (at least partly) a WP-related question again.)

Comment: Good idea to update your question, or if you feel like you've narrowed down the issue then posting a new more specific question with the new details might also be a good idea